code to include a column or more based on checkbox
I have this code that sends a range as a picture into an outlook email. I added checkboxes and want to be able to modify the code to send the contents in range B4:B17 and one or all of C,D, and E depending on if the checkbox is true.
I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help me?
I did post this on the mrexcel forum but was unable to get a working solution:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/code-to-include-a-column-or-more-based-on-checkbox.1265484/#post-6222439
Sub Screen2ShotMain()
Dim rng As Range
Dim olApp As Object
Dim Email As Object
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range
Rows("11:11").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Set rng = Sheets("Calc").Range("B4:C16")
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With Email
  '.To = "damor"
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .Subject = "Forward Commitment" ' & Range("F5").Value
  .Body = "Please see details of forward commitment as discussed" & vbCr & vbCr
  .Display
  DoEvents
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set wdRng = wdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    wdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
  .Display
End With

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set Email = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Rows("11:11").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
End Sub


Can you please edit your questions and be more specific - how many check boxes do you have, what do you want each check box to do?

Assuming that your check boxes are Form Controls you could do something like the following.  It's just a quick and dirty way of doing it but should give you an idea of what to do:
Sub Screen2ShotMain()
    Dim rngB As Range, rngC As Range, rngD As Range, rngE As Range, rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdRng As Word.Range
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    
    With Sheets("Calc")
        .Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set rngB = .Range("B4:B17")
        
        'You can use .CheckBoxes("Check box name instead, click on the checkbox to check its name") instead
        If .CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1 Then Set rngC = .Range("C4:C17") Else Set rngC = Nothing
        If .CheckBoxes(2).Value = 1 Then Set rngD = .Range("D4:D17") Else Set rngD = Nothing
        If .CheckBoxes(3).Value = 1 Then Set rngE = .Range("E4:E17") Else Set rngE = Nothing
    
        Set rng = Union(rngB, rngC, rngD, rngE)
        
    End With
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With Email
      '.To = "damor"
      .CC = ""
      .BCC = ""
      .Subject = "Forward Commitment" ' & Range("F5").Value
      .Body = "Please see details of forward commitment as discussed" & vbCr & vbCr
      .Display
      DoEvents
        Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set wdRng = wdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        wdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
      .Display
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    With Sheets("Calc")
        .Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
    End With
End Sub

